How can we access the index of an elements in numpy array?
import numpy as np

np_arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

condition = (np_arr > 2) & (np_arr < 5)

print(condition)

When we print(condition) - we get a boolean array which tells whether condition is True or False.
So, How can we print the indexes of 'True' elements in the boolean array?
Well we can solve this by normal python list but that beats the purpose of numpy i.e to reduce the time complexity to minimum when we use a large dataset.

Use np.where(condition).

use np.nonzero()
